# Regarding playing mp4 file as splash screen at the start of android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to play a mp4 file in the splash screen.I have written code for splash screen java class.But dont know why it is not picking,can anyone guide me...

Below is my java class code

http://pastebin.com/teCuDdcp

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: Are you want to playing mp4 video? As a splash screen right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know best way to how to achieve this, But if I have to do that, Then I am doing something like this,

1.Starting SpalshActivity,

-> onCreate() of splashActivity just start the .mp4 video and put the OnCompletionListener for media player.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            playVideo();
   }


playVideo()
{
  mp = new MediaPlayer();
  mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
  mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
  mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
  mp.setAudioStreamType(2);
  mp.setDataSource(path);
  mp.prepare();
  Log.v(TAG, "Duration:  ===>" + mp.getDuration());
  mp.start();

}
```

2.Calling new Activity on complete the mp4 video. (For this you have implements OnCompletionListener in your activity).

-> on OnComplete the video I called the new Activity.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) 
{
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Simple . :-)

Comment: @user370305..thanks,,,,the code u have edited i will implement this full code in my java class....????

Comment: yes, you can put the playVideo() method in onCreate() of your spalsh activity and implements onComplitionListener in that activity.